# How to add actionbar in android studio

Tags: android, xml

I created a new project in android studio and when I create an activity it no longer generates a `menu_main.xml` file. How do I bring that back?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to create menu_main.xml file manually.

Comment: I did. It did not help

Comment: Which version using ??

Comment: version number 1.5.1

Answer (score 1):

Create the file `menu_main.xml` manually as `xml` file in the `menu` package, add methods `onCreateOptionsMenu` (and inflate your menu file with menu inflater `getMenuInflater()),`and add `onOptionsItemSelected()` method to your activity:

```
//in onCreate add:
final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        //home button
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Now it crashes on startup

Comment: Post your logcat, you probably have a NPE, which should be easy to fix ;) There should be a line in the logcat which links to a line in your code, please check this.

Comment: I do. Apparently v7.toolbar is throwing an error. I can't get this working so I tried that. Gtg thanks for trying

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).